# How to redirect to non-zend link from zend application

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, forward

My application is mixture of simple PHP webpages and zend application. Sometime I need to redirect to simple PHP webpage from zend application's Action.

**For example:**

I want to redirect from `example.com/module/controller/action` to `example.com/simplephp.php`.

I tried `header("Location: example.com/simplephp.php");` but it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the basic redirect action helper allows you to redirect to any URL.

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {

        $this->_redirect('/path/to/any/page.php');
        // or
        $this->_redirect('http://example.com/anypage.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: **'XML tag name mismatch'** error when I used `$this->_redirect('/path/to/any/page.php');` . **'303 Found'** error when I used `$this->_redirect('http://example.com/anypage.php');` In both cases it is not redirected.

Comment: 303 Found isn't an error.  It IS a redirect... Exactly what you want it to be doing.  If you inspect the HTTP response headers you will see there is a Location: header being returned to the URL you provided in $this->_redirect() ...

Comment: The above solution should work just fine.  If it's not working, you may want to check your server environment.  303 seems strange. Zend Framework usually issues a 302 by default and a 301 if you ask it nicely.  For using raw header("Location: url"); you need to exit() right after or Zend Framework will re-write your header with it's own response and not redirect as you want.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument. Request should contain `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 1):

You should manipulate the `request` object, which sends HTTP headers.

If you want to do:

```
header("Location: example.com/simplephp.php");
```

you need:

```
$request->setHeader('Location', 'example.com/simplephp.php', true);
```

Then you need to turn off the layout, view rendering and any other things which are not needed etc.

The easy way to handle the redirects without worrying too much about the details is the [Redirector action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html). You may use it even outside the controller retrieving it's static instance from Helper Broker.

Note, that even if shortened URLs work in almost all of the browsers, you always should specify full URL for location (including protocol and domain name) as specified in HTTP 1.1.